# Recommend/default settings for ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the Recommend/default settings for ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, should we leave both on?

Comment: I disagree with the closure votes, if only because `ANSI_NULLS` is deprecated, and therefore at least that option is not primarily opinion-based, and there is info that can be shared that will be useful to other readers who can't find the documentation...

Comment: not sure why people always want to close my question, I am active participant of SO

Comment: Just FYI, being an active participant does not automatically make any question you ask on-topic. I'm sure some of your questions that have been closed were closed for the right reasons (it just so happens that in this case I disagree).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ANSI_NULLS` should always be `ON`. Always.

Here's why. From [the documentation for `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx):

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

As for `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, that is more of an opinion-based question. I don't really care, because I never set the option explicitly, but if you do use it you should use it consistently everywhere. The reason I don't care is because I never quote identifiers with single or double quotes; I think this is very unreadable and makes them look like string:

```
SELECT 'alias' = "column" FROM "dbo"."table" AS 'alias';
```

Really? I much prefer using square brackets, and even then only when required (e.g. the identifier is a reserved word).

```
SELECT alias = [column] FROM dbo.[table] AS alias;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is the beauty of SO. Much clearer than MSDN documentation.